# No more drive letters in windows

Tags: windows-10

I am soon running out of drive letters in Windows.
I've seen on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652545/windows-what-happens-if-i-finish-drive-letters-they-are-26 that if I run out of letters, no new drives will show up.

Is this information still up to date?

And do the drives only don't show up in explorer or do they not even show up in disk manager? (Computer Manager -> Disk Manager)

Thanks

Using Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this information still up to date?

Yes;  Everything described in that question, the answers to that question, and the relevant documentation are still accurate.

> do the drives only don't show up in explorer or do they not even show up in disk manager?

A disk will appear in Disk Manager regardless if you have assigned a drive letter to it.